# Restrict user to read only from SECONDARY mongoDB replicaSet

Tags: mongodb

Is there such possibility from database backend to force  user to read only from SECONDARY members ?
I would like to restrict some users to not be able to impact performance in PRIMARY replicaset members in my on-premise deployment ( not atlas )

Issue is easy to solve if customer agree adding to the URI

```
readPreference=secondary
```

But I am checking if there is option to force from the database side without asking the customer ...

the only option I have found is to restrict by server IP address:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
 {
 user: "dbuser",
 pwd: "password"
 roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "reporting" } ],
 authenticationRestrictions: [ {
    clientSource: ["192.0.2.0"],
    serverAddress: ["198.51.100.1","192.51.100.2"]
 } ]
}
)
```

Comment: On MongoDB Atlas you can configure an `ANALYTICS` db, which is for read-only purposes and is SECONDARY by definition

Comment: @nimrodserok , just added that the question is related to on-premise , but indeed very useful to know the ANALYTICS option exist in ATLAS thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no supported ways to enforce this from within MongoDB itself apart from the `authenticationRestrictions` configurations for defining users which is noted in the question itself.

Regarding the comments - `ANALYTICS` tag in Atlas are a (automatic) [Replica Set Tag](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/).  Replica set tags themselves can be used in on-premise deployments. But tags are used *in conjunction with* read preference which is set by the client application (at least in the connection string). So that approach/solution really doesn't provide any additional enforcement from read preference alone for the purposes of this question. Additional information about tags can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/#use-tag-sets-in-read-preference) and [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-preference-tags/).

In an 'unsupported'/hacky fashion, you could create the user(s) directly and only on the `SECONDARY` members that you want the client to read from. This would be accomplished by taking the member out of the replica set, starting it up as a standalone, creating the user, and then joining it back to the replica set. While it would probably *work*, there are a number of implications that don't make this a particularly good approach. For example, elections (for high availability purposes) would change the `PRIMARY` (therefore where the client can read from) among other things.

Other approaches to this would be in redirecting/restricting traffic at the network layer. Again not a great approach.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback , I will accept your answer since it give me some fresh ideas ...